# background not stretching to the screen size

Tags: html, css

I have used this code but only the width is stretching. I want the whole image to stretch into the full screen.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LZ55/)

```
body
{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-image: url(http://p1.pichost.me/i/40/1639647.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method I like to use:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LZ55/4/)

```
body { 
  background: url(http://p1.pichost.me/i/40/1639647.jpg) no-repeat fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

what about `background-size: cover;`?

```
body{
 color: white;
 font-family: Verdana;
 background-size: cover;
 background-image: url(http://p1.pichost.me/i/40/1639647.jpg) no-repeat fixed;
}
```

Comment: you could try ``cover`` instead of ``%``. like this: 
``background-size: cover;``

Answer (score 2):

you could use html instead with height:100% and cover as value for background-size or only 100% if you do not mind to see image being streched :
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LZ55/5/)

```
html
{
    height : 100% ;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana;
    background-size: cover;
    background-image: url(http://p1.pichost.me/i/40/1639647.jpg);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LZ55/7/)

```
html
{
    height : 100% ;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-image: url(http://p1.pichost.me/i/40/1639647.jpg);
}
```

you might want to use min-height on HTML : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5LZ55/8/)

```
html
{
    min-height : 100% ;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-image: url(http://p1.pichost.me/i/40/1639647.jpg);
}
```